# Can I have define slick, bootstrap and corusel together?

Tags: php, html, slick.js

I define both client-side-script and relationship resource. There is bootstrap not working with the slick slider. How can I fix this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="crousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="crousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="crousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does "_not working_" mean? Where are you loading the javascript for slick?

Comment: slick slider is working well but bootstrap not working.

Comment: And what does "_bootstrap not working_" mean? Can't access styles? Modals not working? Are you loading the javascript for bootstrap somewhere?

Comment: yes was not able to access style. now i have load the js for bootstrap thank you.